# Why child is clipped in custom toast?

Tags: java, android, toast

I want to create custom toast with, one view which is a little bit out of parent. So I did something like this

This is my custom toast

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toast_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="50dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/digit_display"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="64sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

round_button.xml

```xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#000000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#2C2C2C"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

and in java code I am using it like this

```java
LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
View v = li.inflate(R.layout.toast, null);
TextView numberView = v.findViewById(R.id.digit_display);
TextView descriptionView = v.findViewById(R.id.description);
numberView.setText(number);
descriptionView.setText(description);

Toast t = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
t.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
t.setView(v);
t.show();
```

And I can see my toast. But `digit_display` TextView is clipped from the top but I would like to  see it out of toast (just top of that view). How can I achieve it? If that does not work.

*EDITED*
I try to understand why this example does not work, when if I am using similar structure in other project form simple form it is working.

```xml
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/form_desing"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="25dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:foreground="@drawable/clover_"
            android:contentDescription="@string/fourbit_clover_icon" />

        <include layout="@layout/email_input" />
        <include layout="@layout/password_input" />
        <include layout="@layout/buttons" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

any idea?

Comment: can you please share the image also

Comment: What image? I am not using any image here.

Comment: i mean the above output and your desired output

Comment: code which I added in here you can copy&paste easily and see what my output is. It is called `Minimal, Reproducible Example` and desired output you can see in link in post below. But `But digit_display TextView is clipped from the top, but I would like to see it out of toast (just top of that view).` is clear enough to understand, I think?

Answer (score 0):

Think of  outer-most `Layout` as your `Toast`'s root view and arrange items inside it. You're NOT limited to only use one `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` . Don't try to go out from root view: It will get clipped.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="top|center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:background="#0A93E1"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:text="Text"
            android:id="@+id/digit_display"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text"
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_below="@id/digit_display"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: photo]

Comment: But this is not want I want to achieve. I want to have circle in my toast which looks like one of those in link https://wedevs.com/138926/hacks-beautiful-form-design-wordpress-form-builder/

Comment: Updated the sample layout in my answer to show it is still possible to do. It is a matter of how you handle and arrange items in layout.

Comment: Thank you for finding solution for me, but I would like to know why my does not work. Can not understand it. Always in toast when you try go out of the `root` tag it is clipped? I have very similar(like my toast, added form in post) structure in other project and it works, that why I can not understand, why is not working in toast?